# Why is my notification campaign not continuing to send

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Essentially we have Firebase campaigns set-up to run with the following parameters:
[image]

Target : User Segment
Target User if:

- App Android
- First Open Between 1 and two days

Or

- App Android
- First Open Between 1 and two days

The schedule is set up as follows:
[image]

The `<firstopen>` parameter is set up as you would expect.

I hoped that the campaign would send daily

The question I have is, why does the campaign only send once and not continue to send every day with renewed targetting?